# Create directory for user with their User Name in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create directory for every user by their own user name, i have written this code

```
<?php
if (!file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/[User Name]/avatar/big')) {
    mkdir(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/[User Name]/avatar/big', 0777, true);
}
?>
```

i want to replace [User name] with the users User Name.

in my MySQL database username column is UserName.

**This is web.config.php file content**

Adding path to avatar is in section 16.

```
<?php
//------------------------------------------------------------
// comment out if output_buffering is already turned on
//------------------------------------------------------------
ob_start();

//------------------------------------------------------------
// turn off magic quotes
//------------------------------------------------------------
ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc', 1); // 1=on 0=off

//------------------------------------------------------------
// instantiate sessions
//------------------------------------------------------------
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
  session_start();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
// 0. WARN IF IE EXPLODER IS LESS THAN 9.0
//------------------------------------------------------------
define('DETECT_IE', 1); // 1=Yes 0=No

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 1. ROOT PATH FOR INCLUDE FILES
// ------------------------------------------------------------
//define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/psum/'); // psum is subdirectory
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 2. WEBSITE ADDRESS
// ------------------------------------------------------------
function siteURL()
{
    $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
    $domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.'authentication/'; // psum is subdirectory
    return $protocol.$domainName;
}
define( 'SITE_URL', siteURL() );

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 3. ACCOUNT ACTIVATION URL
// ------------------------------------------------------------
function verificationURL()
{
    $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
    $domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.'authentication/'; // psum is subdirectory
    $pageName = 'account-activation.php';
    return $protocol.$domainName.$pageName;
}
define( 'ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_URL', verificationURL() );

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 4. DEFAULT LOGIN DESTINATION URL
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// if USE_DEFAULT_LOGIN_DESTINATION is set to 1, all users will be
// redirected to DEFAULT_LOGIN_DESTINATION_URL after login, except
// the users who's destination URL has been custom set in admin panel.
define( 'USE_DEFAULT_LOGIN_DESTINATION', 0 ); // 1=On 0=Off
define( 'DEFAULT_LOGIN_DESTINATION_URL', siteURL().'../index.php' ); // global login destination

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 5. DEFAULT THEMES - CSS
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define( 'SITE_STYLE', SITE_URL.'themes/default/default.css' ); // root files non IE
define( 'ADMIN_STYLE', SITE_URL.'admin/themes/default/default.css' ); // admin files
define( 'USER_STYLE', SITE_URL.'user/themes/default/default.css' ); // user area files
define( 'USER_MENU_STYLE', SITE_URL.'user/themes/default/superfish.css' ); // user area files
define( 'ACCORDION_STYLE', SITE_URL.'user/themes/default/accordion.css' ); // user area files
define( 'FEEDBACK_STYLE', SITE_URL.'feedback/themes/default/default.css' ); // feedback form

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 6. EMAIL ADDRESSES
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define( 'NO_REPLY', 'hunzonian@gmail.com' );
define( 'GENERAL_CONTACT', 'hunzonian@gmail.com' );
define( 'BULK_MAIL_TO', 'hunzonian@gmail.com' );

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 7. MINIMUM PASSWORD REQUIREMENTS
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define( 'MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH', 7 ); // set min length
define( 'REQUIRE_NUMBER', 1 ); // 0=no 1=yes
define( 'REQUIRE_SPECIAL_CHAR', 1 ); // 0=no 1=yes
define( 'ALLOW_USERNAME_IN_PASS', 0 ); // 0=no 1=yes
define( 'ALLOW_PW_STRENGTH_CHECK', 1 ); // 0=no 1=yes

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 8. APPROVE NEW ACCOUNT ON CREATION
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define('INSTANT_ACCOUNT_APPROVAL', 0); // 0=no 1=yes
define('BY_ADMIN_APPROVAL_ONLY', 0); // 0=no 1=yes

// notify admin on new registration
define('REGISTRATION_NOTIFICATION', 0); // 0=no 1=yes
// notify admin on account activation
define('ACTIVATION_NOTIFICATION', 0); // 0=no 1=yes

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 9. DEFAULT ROLES IN ORDER OF PRIORITY
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// owner = 1
// superadmin = 2
// admin = 3
// member = 4
// user = 5
define('DEFAULT_ROLE', "user");
define('DEFAULT_ROLE_ID', 5);

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 10. MAX NUMBER OF LOGIN ATTEMPTS BEFORE LOCKOUT
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define('MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPT', 4);
define('LOCKOUT_DURATION', 1); // minutes

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 11. AUTO LOGIN DURATION - Remember me cookie
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define('AUTO_LOGIN_DURATION', 1728000); // 20 days in seconds

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 12. GRIDVIEW DEFAULT PAGE SIZE
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define('GV_PAGE_SIZE', 10); // rows

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 13. RECAPTCHA KEYS - GET YOURS @ http://www.google.com/recaptcha
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define( 'RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY', "6LeV3r4SAAAAADURcKoSWySxTj9CQyJXHD57yO1z" );
define( 'RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY', "6LeV3r4SAAAAABp2Q2bjyjCRW8E6vvZ06oM6-6yj" );

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 14. ENABLE DISABLE CAPTCHA
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define('LOGIN_CAPTCHA_ON', 0); // 1=on 0=off
define('REGISTER_CAPTCHA_ON', 1); // 1=on 0=off
define('FEEDBACK_CAPTCHA_ON', 1); // 1=on 0=off
define('CAPTCHA_ON_X', 3); // turn captcha ON after x failure

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 15. USER PROFILES
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define('ENABLE_USER_PROFILES', 1); // 1=yes 0=no

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 16. AVATAR IMAGE FILE
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define('AVATAR_FILE_SIZE', 2097152); // 50 Kb max. -> 1 kilobyte = 1024 bytes
define('AVATAR_FILE_DIRECTORY', ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/avatars/'); // upload directory
define('AVATAR_IMAGE_URL', SITE_URL.'user/upload/avatars/'); // default avatar url
define('DEFAULT_AVATAR_IMAGE', 'default-avatar.png'); // default avatar image

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 17. UNIQUE VISITORS ONLINE COUNTER
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define('ENABLE_VISITOR_COUNT', 0); // 1=yes 0=no
define('LAST_X_MINUTES', 15); // counts number of visitors in last x minutes

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 18. FEEDBACK / CONTACT FORM
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// company logo
define('COMPANY_LOGO_SIZE', 51200); // 50 Kb max. -> 1 kilobyte = 1024 bytes
define('COMPANY_LOGO_DIRECTORY', ROOT_PATH.'feedback/upload/'); // upload directory
define('COMPANY_LOGO_URL', SITE_URL.'feedback/upload/'); // default logo url
define('DEFAULT_COMPANY_LOGO', 'company.png'); // default logo image

// contact email form
define('MIN_FEEDBACK_LENGTH', 20); // min. text length
define('MAX_FEEDBACK_LENGTH', 1000); // max text length
define('MIN_FEEDBACK_WORDS', 3); // min number of words

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 19. PREMIUM MEMBERSHIP
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define('ENABLE_PREMIUM_MEMBERSHIP', 0); // 1=yes 0=no
define('HIDE_PREMIUM_MEMBERSHIP_IN_ADMIN', 0); // 1=yes 0=no

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 20. SCHEDULED MAINTENANCE
// ------------------------------------------------------------
/*
if set to 1, all pages with the following constant in their
header will be redirected to the page defined below.
*/
define('SCHEDULED_MAINTENANCE', 0); // 1=show 0=hide
define('UNDER_CONSTRUCTION_PAGE', SITE_URL.'maintenance.html');

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 21. SHOW / HIDE THE FOLLOWING MODULES
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define('SHOW_REGISTRATION', 1); // 1=yes 0=no
define('SHOW_PASSWORD_RESET', 1); // 1=yes 0=no
define('SHOW_LOST_USER_NAME', 1); // 1=yes 0=no
define('SHOW_RESEND_ACTIVATION', 1); // 1=yes 0=no

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 22. SHOW / HIDE ADMIN STICKY BUTTON BAR
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define('SHOW_STICKY_BAR', 1); // 1=yes 0=no

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 23. PROTECTED DOWNLOAD
// ------------------------------------------------------------
define('ENABLE_DOWNLOADS', 1); // 1=yes 0=no
define('DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY',  ROOT_PATH.'download/'); // protected download directory
define('MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE', 20971520); // 20 Mb max. -> 1 megabyte = 1048576 bytes

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// 24. ACCOUNT SHARING
// ------------------------------------------------------------
/*
if set to 0, only the latest login per account is valid and
all others will be logged off. If set to 1, each account
can be used simultaneously by multiple users.
*/
define('ACCOUNT_SHARING', 0); // 1=allowed 0=not allowed
```

Comment: Use a `SELECT` query, and utilise a variable like `$row['UserName']` to bring in the information you need to create a directory. Don't use `MySQL_*` functions though, look into `PDO` or `MySQLi`

Comment: Can you please guide my how to do it

Comment: Have given you an idea of what to do in my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is what you are after. It will give you enough information to get started, but you will need to look into setting up the `new PDO` part and amend the query to match what you are looking for:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO("..."); // Connection details here
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from some_table where user_id = :id"); // Finds the information based on an ID. Change this depending on how you want the select to work
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => "1")); // Gives value to :id and executes the statement
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    // Then run your code

    if (!file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/big')) {
        mkdir(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/big', 0777, true);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy, you saved my day. Fortunately it worked. i had another question that can i create multiple folders like this for example i want to create another folder by the name of small and another by the name of original.

Comment: @arafi If this has helped you please accept it as the correct answer :) you can but that needs to be a separate question from this one

Comment: As i said, you need to set up the code correctly with a database connection etc. If you've done that, try adding the code of web.config.php to your question because i cant help without seeing the code

Comment: You have to make sure the PDO connection block i showed you is defined above where you request anything to do with $row

Comment: These questions are nothing to do with the answer i gave you however, you would be better off starting a new question if you are still having trouble with a different file

Comment: @arafi why have you removed the accepted mark on the question? My answer answered your original query. The issues you have now aren't to do with the original question.

Comment: above code that you provided is working in other pages but not in this page web.config.php

Comment: @arafi Exactly, so there isn't anything wrong with my code, it's where you're placing it. Please mark the answer as accepted as it is the **original answer** to your **original question**

Comment: @arafi As i keep saying, you are now experiencing issues with something that isn't the original question. Please create a new question, and mark this answer as accepted

Comment: Please see the new question regarding multiple directory creation
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971188/how-to-create-multiple-directory-for-users-by-their-user-name/25971279?noredirect=1#comment40665340_25971279)

Comment: Will take a look for you :)