# How to create multiple directory for users by their user name

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code that i want to make it able to create multiple directory for users by their username.

Right now it creates only one folder by the name of `big`

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO("..."); // Connection details here
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from some_table where user_id = :id"); // Finds the information based on an ID. Change this depending on how you want the select to work
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => "1")); // Gives value to :id and executes the statement
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    // Then run your code

    if (!file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/big')) {
        mkdir(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/big', 0777, true);
    }
?>
```

i want two other directory like this:

```
user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/small

user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/original
```

Comment: Just don't. Honestly: don't. Really... while it _is_ possible, you really shouldn't even dare to think about dreaming to contemplate going down this path. There be dragons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is modify the original script I gave you to the following:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO("..."); // Connection details here
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from some_table where user_id = :id"); // Finds the information based on an ID. Change this depending on how you want the select to work
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => "1")); // Gives value to :id and executes the statement
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    // Then run your code

    if (!file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/big')) {
        mkdir(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/big', 0777, true);
    }

    if (!file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/small')) {
        mkdir(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/small', 0777, true);
    }

    if (!file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/original')) {
        mkdir(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/original', 0777, true);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Really Appreciated. can i use UserName instead of user_id

Comment: You can, you can change the select statement to whatever will work for you. That logic above is just something i personally use to make things work :)

Comment: If i change it to use `UserName` instead of `user_id` then what should i put instead of `:id`

Comment: You need to research how to use PDO. you can change it to whatever you want, it's the value of :id you need to worry about. Please do research into using PDO objects/bound parameters. I can't give a tutorial over comments

Answer (score 2):

You already have the solution here dont you. Just keep doing what you are already doing..

```
if( !is_dir( (ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/big' ) ){
    mkdir(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/big', 0777, true);
}

if( !is_dir ( (ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/big' ) ){
    mkdir(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/big', 0777, true);
}
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through your results and create directories (is_dir is faster than file_exists)

```
$db = new PDO("..."); // Connection details here
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from some_table where user_id = :id"); // Finds the information based on an ID. Change this depending on how you want the select to work
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => "1")); // Gives value to :id and executes the statement

// Then run your code
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

    array_walk(array('big', 'small', 'original'), function(&$v, $k) {   
        $dir = ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/' . $v;
        if (!is_dir($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it gives me error please see the jsfiddle link for more clarification http://jsfiddle.net/g6antdqy/

Comment: it just says that your constants aren't defined, why are you using constants anyway ? just store path to simple var. Defining a constant in a while loop it's kinda useless

Comment: I use a configuration file in whole my website by the name of web.config.php and i store all the setting there so please have a look through help me to fix the error. This is the file. Find avatar setting in section 16..... http://jsfiddle.net/60fhooLf/

Comment: I can't help you much more with what you gave me, the error you have it's that, while fetching the records from your DB, in the while loop you are missing the constant AVATAR_FILE_DIRECTORY, try to investigate this way

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a single folder of the user name and than create other folder under the user name folder as per your need and there access would be similar.

```
if (!file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/big')) {
    @mkdir(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/big', 0777, true); 
}
if (!file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/small')) {
    @mkdir(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/small', 0777, true);
}
if (!file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/original')) {
    @mkdir(ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/original', 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: how it should check whether the folder exist or not

Comment: and avoid at all costs using @, as it's equivalent to: disabling error handler, calling mkdir, enabling error handler etc. , really bad for performances